# How to collect all chains by using python3

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

**Background:**

I'm doing polymer simulation. And I'm trying to use `networkx` to calculate how many chains in the system. Molecules inside systems are equal to the nodes and bonds equal to the connection between nodes.

**What I have tried:**

I used `networkx.chain_decompostion` to calculate the number of the chain.

```
import networkx as nx
info = nx.chain_decomposition(G)
```

**Issues:**

I found it only find the chains which are closed loop, such as `A1-A2-A3-A1`.

However, there are still many chains are not closed, such as `A1-A2-A3`.

Is there an easy way to collect both types of the chains. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `chain_decomposition` is not what you think it is. From the docs:

> The chain decomposition of a graph with respect a depth-first search tree is a set of cycles or paths derived from the set of fundamental cycles of the tree [...]

What you are probably looking for is the function `number_connected_components`. 
See [this link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/algorithms.component.html) for details. This assumes that each connected component is a chain, i.e. that there are several disjoint subgraphs in your graph G, each corresponding to a (non-branching) polymer molecule. If that is not the case (the polymer is branched) then I you need to do something a bit more clever. For example, you could compute all shortest paths between leave nodes (atoms with a single bond).
You can find the leaf nodes by inspecting the degree of the nodes with `list(G.degree)` (leaves have degree 1), and then compute the shortest paths with between all leaf pairs with `all_shortest_paths`.
To find cyclic molecules you can use `chain_decomposition` as before.

Comment: This exactly what I am looking for! Really appreciate!